# How to implement HD74HC32 (quadruple 2-input positive-OR gate)?

Tags: digital-logic, breadboard

I'm struggling to implement the `HD74HC32` (quadruple 2-input positive-OR gate) package:
[image]

My breadboard looks as following:
[image]

Notes:

- `1.8` volt power supply, sufficient according to the `HD74HC32` datasheet
- `1A` is located at the left bottom
- `Vcc` connected to `[+]` and `GND` connected to `[-]`
- `1Y` connected to `LED Anode`
- `LED cathode` connected to `[-]`

I tried every possible combination, with and without resistors, but I cannot get the gate to work.  The LED even stays on while `1A` and `1B` are disconnected.

How do I get this OR gate to work as expected?

The following question looks alike, but I just can't get it to work `:(`
[Connecting AND Gate Chip to an Integrated Circuit](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34051/connecting-and-gate-chip-to-an-integrated-circuit)

*My reputation is too low to embed images, that's why linked directly, sorry!*

Comment: Can you link the datasheet? Why do you use 1.8V?

Comment: Thanks for your edit and comment! The [`HD74HC32`](http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheet/HitachiSemiconductor/mXvstyv.pdf) datasheet. I choose the 1.8 volt because I ran out of proper resistors for the LED to work with 5 volt. I'm just "playing around" with logic gates for the first time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On CMOS IC's like the one you are using, unused input pins float high. This means that if nothing is connected to them, the circuit will act as if they have a Vcc input applied to them. To resolve this, connect inputs you want to have a value of '0' to ground.

Comment: Thanks four your quick and clear answer, greatly appreciated! Works like a charm `:)`

Comment: No, they don't float high, they simply float. **All** 8 inputs to this chip should be driven (or tied) high or low at all times.