# TTL 7400 NAND gate circuit not functioning

Tags: ttl, nand

I recently made a circuit using the ttl 7400 NAND gate IC. The concept is simple. There are two 4 bit inputs going into the 7400 IC. The 7400 IC does a 4 bit NAND operation on these bits, and outputs them. The outputs are used to drive 4 LED's(each LED represents one bit). I made the circuit and it does nothing. The LED's are all off when all input bits are LOW. If I change the input bits nothing happens. Here is a chart to sumarize the behavior of the circuit I built:

[image]

As you can see, no matter what the input the outputs is always 0000.

Here is a diagram of the circuit:

[image]

Here is the data sheet of the 7400 IC(I'm not sure who manufactured the chip but it says 7400N on it): http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls00.pdf

(The top left diagram on the data sheets first page is the 7400's pinout diagram)

Comment: Draw a proper schematic (a fritzing diagram of a breadboard is not a schematic) and also upload a picture of your circuit.

Comment: If your breadboard is a double length one like shown, remember that typically there is a break in the power rail at the centre point, so it is possible that the GND and VCC are not connected to your NAND. But without an actual photo that is a guess.

Comment: Also you are not connecting your inputs properly. You are connecting them to switches so that the inputs are either connected to VCC or left floating. A 7400 series TTL device like the one you have has internal pull ups, which means when floating the pins will pull high - basically all your inputs are always high. Your switches should connect to GND.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Tom. I followed your advice and connected the input switches to GND instead of VCC. Now the circuit functions as an OR Gate which is weird. I will update my question with a schematic diagram and a picture of the circuit. It might take me a while though, since I'm not free for the next hour. Thanks.

Comment: Makes sense. If you invert both inputs of a NAND gate, you get an OR gate. Now that when the switches are pressed the input is a zero - so you need to remember that closed = 0, open = 1. I'll write all this up as an answer in a little while, just having dinner.

Comment: This seems a near duplicate to the issues explained in ["Connecting AND Gate Chip to an Integrated Circuit"](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34051/connecting-and-gate-chip-to-an-integrated-circuit) (although a different TTL IC) i.e. switches connected to VCC with no pull-down resistors on the TTL inputs (well spotted @TomCarpenter).

Comment: Tom thanks for the explanation, I understand what you are saying. I am making a series of small circuits that perform basic boolean logic and combining them to form a functioning ALU. For this reason I don't want to add unnecessary chips. Is the only solution to add a 4 bit bit not gate between the switch's output and the 7400 input? This would require two more IC's. Is there a way to make the circuit function as a NAND gate without these two IC's? Sorry if this question doesn't make sense I'm a newbie.

Comment: Just treat the switch being closed as a 0. You don't need any extra circuitry - the inversion can be built into your head with no electronics required.

Comment: I think that that the "in my head inversion " is a good idea for this circuit. In the ALU, I will probably just add a not gate chip to both the inputs before they go to the NAND gate. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The LED's are all off when all input bits are LOW

No, your input bits are *never* low. When a switch is ON it connects +5V to an input. When the switch is OFF it connects *nothing*, and the input is 'floating'. Floating is not LOW. In TTL logic, LOW is a voltage between 0V and 0.8V (see datasheet page 4, "V<sub>IL</sub> Low-level input voltage").

Perhaps you thought that with nothing connected the input would naturally go down to 0V. But it won't, because the input circuit of a TTL NAND gate looks like this (datasheet page 3):-

[image]

I added a red line to show how voltage gets from Vcc to the input pin. With nothing connected the input will float at about 1.8V. To make the input LOW you must sink the Input Low current (I<sub>IL</sub>, datasheet page 4) by pulling the input below 0.8V.

There are two ways to pull an input LOW with a switch. One way is to connect a pull down resistor from the input to ground. Since I<sub>IL</sub> can be up to 1.6mA, and the voltage across the resistor needs to be less than 0.8V, the resistance value must be less than 0.8V/1.6mA = 500Ω. This method has the disadvantage that when the switch is ON it puts 5V across the resistor, which wastes current.

The other way is to connect the switch to Ground rather than +5V, then switch ON = LOW. Since TLL inputs float high you may get away with just doing this, but to produce a properly defined HIGH (>=2.4V) you should add a pull up resistor to Vcc. Input High current (I<sub>IH</sub>) is only 40uA, so a large value resistor will do, eg. 10KΩ. There is still some wasted current, but much less than with a pull down resistor.

Comment: Used the first method you described using 220Ω resistors and it worked perfectly. Thanks.